# issue when i modifying the Message Label using gmail API in c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to removing the message label. I am able to read the mail successfully, but when I am trying to modify the message Label i have a problem

> An error occurred: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Insufficient Permission [403]
>   Errors 
>   Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermis
>   sions] Domain[global]

i had to try to created a service from json but it have a same issue.
and this is my code

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                },
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose },//new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
```

and then i call api to modify label UNREAD in message

```
ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
mods.AddLabelIds = null;
mods.RemoveLabelIds = new List<string> { "UNREAD" });
service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, userId, messageId).Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your scopes either add

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels Create, read, update, and delete labels only.

or just request

> https://mail.google.com/ Full access to the account, including permanent deletion of threads and messages. This scope should only be requested if your application needs to immediately and permanently delete threads and messages, bypassing Trash; all other actions can be performed with less permissive scopes.

Also removelablesids requests a label **ID**

```
removeLabelIds[]  A list IDs of labels to remove from this message.
```

I don't think *new List { "UNREAD" });* is going to return the label id.   try doing [lables.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list) to find the labels and there ids

Comment: i try to use GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom and GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels. but it not work

Comment: tks @DalmTo so much. i had resolve my issue. i go to this link and remove permission and run app again.and then it work perfect. https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1